# How can I bring up the list of items by searching through my hash_key, in dynamo?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in `dynamo` that has the `hash_key`: `Name` (`String`) and 3 more global indexes.
I need to search and bring the list of items where my `Name` == `myNameToSearch` for example.
But I'm having trouble fetching using getItem. And I have items in dynamo.
I am facing this error:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400
```

But my hash_key is correct...

Here my Class DynamoDbConfig:

```
@Getter
@Singleton
@Slf4j
public class DynamoDBConfig {
    private DynamoDbTable<MyModel> table;

    public DynamoDBConfig(Config config) {
        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(DynamoDbClient.builder().build())
                .build();

        String tableName = config.getValue("myDynamoTable");
        table = enhancedClient.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(MyModel.class));
    }
}
```

My class to search in dynamo:

```
@Service
@Singleton
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BringFromDynamo {

    private final DynamoDBConfig config;

    protected Void doExecute() {

        
        config.getTable().getItem(Key.builder().partitionValue("myNameToSearch").build()); //error

    }
}
```

My model:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@DynamoDbBean
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MyModel implements Serializable {

public static final String MYNAME = "Name";
public static final String ANOTHER_FIELD_GLOBAL_INDEX = "anotherField";

    @JsonProperty(MYNAME)
    @Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbAttribute(MYNAME), @DynamoDbPartitionKey})
    private String myName;

    @JsonProperty(ANOTHER_FIELD_GLOBAL_INDEX)
    @Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbAttribute(ANOTHER_FIELD_GLOBAL_INDEX)})
    private LocalDate anotherField;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding how primary keys work in DynamoDB.

It sounds like you have a composite primary key, which means you have both a partition key and a sort key.  The `getItem` operation works by fetching an item by the full primary key (partition key **and** sort key).  You cannot use getItem to fetch by sort key alone, which is what the DynamoDB error is telling you

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

If you want to fetch using the value of the sort key alone, you have a few options;

1. Use `scan` to find the items of interest. This is not ideal but is an option if you cannot change your data model.
2. Create a global secondary index (GSI) that swaps your partition key and sort key values. This pattern is called an inverted index. This would allow you to identify all items with a given user name.

Comment: I cannot scan the base, as it will be millions of items. Having a secondary global index, can I not search using my partition key?

Comment: You mentioned that you have a hash key of `name`, but I don't see that anywhere in your code.  What does your table look like?  The error is likely a mismatch between what DDB is using as a primary key and the value you are providing to the getItem operation